# Vue.js - How to access POST data from external request (Greasemonkey)?

Tags: http, post, vue.js

I'm trying to sending POST data from browser with  Greasemonkey script ( current page url, and name) to http://localhost:8080/service (Bookmark manager app).

I tested POST request to the service route in Postman witch resulted in error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /service</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to access the external POST data in Vue.js app?
Here is the router code fragment:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import pageService from "@/pages/PageService";
Vue.use(Router);


export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/service",
      name: "Service",
      component: pageService,
      props: true
    }

    ]

});
```